# Using angularjs promises within d3js code

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angular-promise, angular-translate

I am trying to find a way to use angular promises with d3js...

I have simplified my code into the following snippet:

```
d3.select("body")
    .append("span")
    .text(function (d) {
         $translate("SOME_KEY" + d.name).then(function (translation) {
           return translation;
         });
    });
```

The issue is that, of course the `.text()` invocation returns before the result of the promise is returned by the `$translate` service.

Can someone please provide a solution to the above problem?

P.S. *For completeness' sake, it must be mentioned that $translate is the angular translate service and that the above code runs from within a ng 1.5 component controller.*

edit: Here is the full code:

```
d3Service.d3().then(function (d3) {
    var diameter = 300;

    var svg = d3.select($element[0])
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', diameter)
        .attr('height', diameter);

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
        .size([diameter, diameter])
        .value(function (d) {
            return d.size;
        })
        .padding(5);

    var nodes = bubble.nodes(ctrl.d3Data)
        .filter(function (d) {
            return !d.children;
        });

var vis = svg
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    });

vis.append('circle')
    .attr('r', function (d) {
        return d.r;
    })
    .attr('class', function (d) {
        return d.className;
    });

vis.append('text')
    .text(function (d) {
        $translate('DOMAIN_ENUM.CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPE.' + d.name).then(function (translation) {
            return translation;
        });
    })
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('font-size', 'small')
    .style('fill', 'white');
 });
```

Comment: Why not just flip it around an run the entire `d3` block in the promise?

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for your comment. Is it feasible? The thing is I have multiple elements to translate. One per item in the array... I have included the full code. Can you please explain how what you suggested can be achieved?